# FastCGI cleanup code does not work under windows

Tags: c++, c, windows, apache, fastcgi

Using apache on a windows server with mod_fastcgi, the C code looks like that:

```
void main() {
    init();
    while (FCGI_Accept() >= 0)
        work();
    cleanup();
}
```

When the service is taken down (i.e.: net stop apache2), the process terminates without getting to the cleanup code.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Well does the FCGI_Accept() ever return a nagatice number? Or do you just halt the process?

Comment: I'm not halting the process. I take apache's service down (net stop apache2), and this should cause FCGI_Accept() to return with a negative value, if I understand correctly.

Answer (score 4):

It seems, from reading the `FCGI_Accept` manpage and [this FAQ entry](http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/node/6?q=node/18#signals) that `FCGI_Accept` does not, in fact, return -1 in the case of Apache shutting down.  Try setting a signal handler for SIGUSR1 and SIGTERM.  There's an example (not Windows-specific, but it's worth a try) posted a while ago [on a mailing list, here.](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.web.fastcgi.devel/590)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to exit prematurely would be to call "exit()" somewhere inside work() (or FCGI_Accept()...)

**Edit:**

If you think it might be FCGI_Accept(), try using onexit() to set up a callback to be called from "exit()". At the very least this will confirm that "exit()" was called prematurely.

Comment: 1. I don't want to exit without the cleanup (which is the case right now), and 2. FCGI_Accept is part of the FastCGI framework and should return with <0 when commanded by apache to go down (at least as I understand it). Instead, it aborts...

Comment: You could try using "onexit()" - this sets a function to be executed when a program terminates.